# Disable script in asp.net complete project

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How to disable script through web.config.

I tried this code but didn't works

````
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx"
      type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
       validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
<system.web>```
````

Comment: Why do you want to disable script. Here is a [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28733/prevent-iis-from-executing-scripts-in-a-specific-directory) which can help you.

Comment: I'm saving some HTML in database through script. I don't want to run that script through web. I'll change it manually.
2nd thing enable scripting is not good for security.

Comment: So you have some html which contains javascript as well. You are saving it to database and then rendering it on the web page. As far script is concern it will run on browser how you are going to stop it. [Here is further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8)